Flask-SocketIO v5.2.0 join_room sid key error when using python-socketio v5.11.2
python-socketio v5.11.2 is causing my flask server (Flask-SocketIO v5.2.0) to create a key error when invoking join_room.
Client first connects, then returns a key error when joining a room.
It seems that the server has not registered the Client's sid?
I'm not seeing this when using python-socketio v5.6.0
Exception in thread Thread-48578:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 730, in _handle_event_internal
    r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 755, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 283, in _handler
    *args)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 766, in _handle_event
    ret = handler(*args)
  File "routes.py", line 23, in request_session_data
    join_room(semid)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 924, in join_room
    socketio.server.enter_room(sid, room, namespace=namespace)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 436, in enter_room
    self.manager.enter_room(sid, namespace, room)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socketio/base_manager.py", line 124, in enter_room
    eio_sid = self.rooms[namespace][None][sid]
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bidict/_base.py", line 530, in __getitem__
    return self._fwdm[key]
KeyError: 'a_dJOzmVenu8VPajAAVt'

Thanks for taking a look. Big fan of Flask-Socketio/python-socketio, please let me know what I can do to help.

Sorry, but without minimal working example it will be very hard to debug your issue.

Please include a small client and server with your question to help in reproducing this issue.

Yes of course! Sorry for the delay. I'm having trouble reproducing the issue...The flask server is using Python 3.7...which may be a bit moldy.

It seems that I had removed aiohttp via pip. I don't understand why the missing library wasn't caught, but in this case it was needed to operate properly. Thanks for your help!
